# Using an Case function in a MySQL SELECT query then select

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to use an Case statement in a MySQL select query. 
I am getting an error (Subquery returns more than 1 row)

```
    SELECT mony.come,mony.go,mony.details,mony.id_bill,
    (
     case mony.details
        when 'collect' then (SELECT collect_from_customer.num FROM collect_from_customer INNER JOIN mony ON mony.id_bill = collect_from_customer.id WHERE collect_from_customer.id=mony.id_bill )
        when 'pay_to_cust' then (SELECT pay_to_customer.num FROM pay_to_customer INNER JOIN mony ON mony.id_bill = pay_to_customer.id WHERE pay_to_customer.id=mony.id_bill )
    end
) as idd 
,mony.date FROM mony
```

please help me

Comment: I am not seeing any `if`...you are using a `case` statement and the error that you are having is because your subqueries are returning more that one row...you can test adding `limit 1` to each one of your subqueries.

Comment: you are Right ... sorry, when select (mony.id_bill) need use this value to select another

Comment: If you can *edit* your question and include this detail, that will make it much easier for others to answer `:@)`

Comment: thanks -Martin for your interest

Answer (score -1):

thanks i found solution

```
SELECT m.come,m.go,m.details,m.id_bill,
(
case m.details
        when 'collect' then (SELECT collect_from_customer.num FROM collect_from_customer INNER JOIN mony m1 ON m1.id_bill = collect_from_customer.id WHERE collect_from_customer.id=m.id_bill LIMIT 1 )
        when 'pay_to_cust' then (SELECT pay_to_customer.num FROM pay_to_customer INNER JOIN mony m1 ON m1.id_bill = pay_to_customer.id WHERE pay_to_customer.id=m.id_bill LIMIT 1 )
end
) as idd 
,m.date FROM mony m
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a solution to any problem :-(